# dealing with multiple values in a column using python

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm new to pandas and pivot functions in python and need some help.

How can I use python pandas or pivot table to covert this table to the output below:

```
No  class
1   U234
2   U234,U237,U239
3   U238,U239,U234
4   U237,U234
```

Required output:

```
No  class
1   U234
2   U234
2   U237
2   U239
3   U238
3   U239
3   U234
4   U237
4   U234
```

Comment: What does `df.dtypes say`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `class` to `DataFrame`, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it and create new `Series` with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html):

```
print (df['class']
             .str
             .split(',', expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('class'))
0    U234
0    U237
1    U234
1    U237
1    U239
2    U238
2    U239
2    U234
3    U237
3    U234
Name: class, dtype: object
```

Then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) original column `class` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) new `Series`:

```
print (df.drop('class', axis=1)
             .join
             (
             df['class']
             .str
             .split(',', expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('class')           
             ))

   No class
0   1  U234
0   1  U237
1   2  U234
1   2  U237
1   2  U239
2   3  U238
2   3  U239
2   3  U234
3   4  U237
3   4  U234
```

If in column `class` in **NO** `NaN` values:

```
print (pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in df['class'].tolist() ])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
         .rename('class'))
0    U234
0    U237
1    U234
1    U237
1    U239
2    U238
2    U239
2    U234
3    U237
3    U234
Name: class, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. For some reason, I got errors like:      ----> 1 print (pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in test['class'].tolist() ])          .stack()          .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)          .rename('class'))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I think you have older version of `pandas`. What is `pd.__version__` ?

Comment: Mine is: u'0.17.1'.  Perhaps I should upgrade?

Comment: Yes, my version is last - `0.18.1`  and it works very nice. If use `Anaconda` and `windows`, use in `cmd` - `conda install pandas`

Comment: Yes it works fine! Thanks again @jezrael. Kindly explain - why do we need to rename in the first step and also drop and rename in the second step.

Comment: You have to first remove original column `class` and replace it to new `column` with same name - so you need first drop oroginal. And then you need rename series, because after join you get from `series name` column name. Is it clearear?